# Logstash azure plugin

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, logstash, azure-blob-storage, iis-logs

I am very new to logstash, and am kind of stuck how to do this part.

I copied logs from azure blob container, and was able to parse via logstash and put the records in elastic search on my local machine.
Now I want to change the input so that instead of file, it gets the logs directly from the azure blob storage.
I looked for plugins, but did not find anything for azure.

I am hoping I can do something like this in the input. Any ideas how to get this?

```
input {
  azureblob {
    storage_name => "abcd"
    storage_key => "key"
    container => "logLocation"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around, and reading a bunch of stuff, I got it to work on my local windows machine.

Install ruby.
Install jruby.
command line -> gem install bundle.

Above is needed to build gems

Then I got these files.
https://github.com/juliusl/logstash-input-azurewadtable/tree/0.9.2

Replaced lib/logstash/inputs/azurewadtable.rb with https://github.com/mspnp/semantic-logging/blob/elk/ELK/logstash-extension/inputs/azureblob.rb

Replaced all places with azurewadtable with azureblob in all files.

Via command line gem install "localtion_Of_gemSpec"
This will give you the gem file.

Logstash\bin\plugin install "location_of_gem_file"
Logstash\bin\plugin install --no-verify

Verify a couple of things:
Logstash\gemfile has this entry and
Logstash\vendor\local_gems has the files

Setup config:

```
﻿input {
  azureblob {
    storage_account_name => "STORAGE ACCOUNT NAME"
    storage_access_key => "STORAGE ACCESS KEY"
    container => "CONTAINER NAME"
  }
```

}

Logstash/bin/logstash -f "location_of_conf_File"

And it works :)

Comment: Hi @Dhrumil Can i send data content from azure blob storage to ES with this logstash input config eventhough the data present in blob isn't in JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

I faced issue while using **lostash-input-azureblob** plugin to fetch azure logs and send them to the desired location. There is still and open issue on github for the same : https://github.com/Azure/azure-diagnostics-tools/issues/170 
 I have found a workaround, in the latest version 0.9.13 there is some files missing which can be downloaded from version 0.9.12, Please follow the below link for detail instructions :
 https://github.com/Azure/azure-diagnostics-tools/issues/170#issuecomment-635286539

Comment: I switched to lostash-input-azure_blob_storage years ago, after I noticed that ingestion would stop for a period, so it wouldn't process all my files. azureblob doesn't seem to be supported anymore